# RDS vs. set up MySQL database on a EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, amazon-rds

I am quite confused about these concepts. What are the advantages of using RDS instead of directly setting up the MySQL database on EC2? I know RDS has a MySQL database engine, and it can automate setting up a database.

Answer (score 0):

The main advantage is an RDS instance is managed for you as opposed to when you install MySQL on EC2, nothing is managed for you. Even installing it is very easy as you fill in a web form.

For more details about what is managed, see:

https://aws.amazon.com/rds/